# Block cyrilic characters in nginx

Tags: nginx

Recently I see a lot off spam messages on a contact form on our website, I was wondering if their was an easy way to block cyrilic (Russian) characters in post data. If such a character is found, it can just cancel the request with a 400 error code.

So something like a reqular expression on the post data, looking for specific byte values (for those unicode chars).

I already added blocking based on a recent GeoIP database, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: do these requests being sent to the specific `location`? Or just random?

Comment: Guess they (automatically) fill the content form and submit it. Already using a captcha… Next thought was, just block all responses with Cyrillic chars in it.

Comment: yes, I suppose, it's better way to do it on application level

Comment: I don’t agree, if the Cyrillic chars are blocked before reaching the application that is even better.

Comment: its up to you anyway, but you can easily sort it out with nginx only if all Cyrillic characters comes in same character set, utf8 in your case, otherwise you might need some other option